# How to set the default run configuration for a project in Rider

Tags: rider, run-configuration

I have a C# solution, with multiple projects, being managed in Rider.
For one project ("Proj1") I have multiple run configurations ("Proj1 A", and "Proj1 B").

By default the project explorer UI offers one of the configurations preferentially:

- "Build Selected Projects"
- "Run 'Proj1 A'"
- "Debug 'Proj1 A'"

but I want to run 'Proj1 B' more often that 'Proj1 A'.

**How can I can set which one is offered by default?**
(It doesn't seem to be done alphabetically, it mostly seems to be "order of creation"!?

Comment: File editing solution found. Proper UI solution welcomed if available.

Comment: @RiderDevs please fix this is there's no UI available currently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Find `\.idea\**\workspace.xml`.
- In that XML file find elements: `<project> -> <component name="RunManager"> -> <list>`.
- Inside the `<list>` element, find `<item>` elements looking like this:

```
<item itemvalue=".NET Project.Proj1 A" />
<item itemvalue=".NET Project.Proj1 B" />
```

Reverse them - Rider appears to use whichever one is listed first as the default run config to offer.